# I am tring to display data from firebase database to listview but getting eror when I create Listadapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, listadapter, firebaseui

I am trying to create a chat listview, but getting an error like Chatadapter android.Context.context java.lang.string in chatdatpter cannot be applien to annonymous com.google.firebase database Java.util.array list.

I am getting the error  bellow line

```
ListAdapter theAdapter = new Chatadapter(this,message);
```

The bellow is the full code.

```
public class Chatactivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

    Button buttonSend;
    EditText chatText;
    ListView L;
    String username;
    String sendid;
    int Request_id;
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<>();
    Messageproperties messageproperties = new Messageproperties();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_activity);
        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        L = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        //Add Data
        //String[] days={"Egg Benedict", "Mushroom Risotto", "Full Breakfast", "Hamburger", "Ham and Egg Sandwich", "Creme Brelee", "White Chocolate Donut", "Starbucks Coffee", "Vegetable Curry", "Instant Noodle with Egg", "Noodle with BBQ Pork", "Japanese Noodle with Pork", "Green Tea", "Thai Shrimp Cake", "Angry Birds Cake", "Ham and Cheese Panini"};

        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

              this.RetriveData();

        });

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                System.out.println("Send Button Pressed");
                chatText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chatText);
                String message = (String) chatText.getText().toString();
                username = userLocalStore.getname();
                sendid = userLocalStore.getToken();
                String req_id = sharedPreferences.getString("requestid", "");                        
                System.out.println("Username====>" + username);
                messageproperties.setDate(formattedDate);
                messageproperties.setMessage(message);
                messageproperties.setSender_id(sendid);
                messageproperties.setSenderDisplayName(username);
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
                myRef.child(req_id).push().setValue(messageproperties);
                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.chatText)).getText().clear();

            }
        });


    }

       //Retrive Data
    private void RetriveData()
    {

         String req_id = sharedPreferences.getString("requestid", "");
       // System.out.println("Now Getting Nsuser Default====>" + req_id);
        myRef.child(req_id).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                Messageproperties newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messageproperties.class);
                message.add(newPost.getMessage());

               // ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Chatactivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, message);
              //  L.setAdapter(adapter);

                ListAdapter theAdapter = new Chatadapter(this,message);
                ListView theListview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                theListview.setAdapter(theAdapter);


            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }
}


//This is Chat Addatter page

package com.app.secretcupid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by vysimac on 11/12/16.
 */
public class Chatadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public Chatadapter(Context context, String[] Values) {
        super(context,R.layout.row_adapter_layout ,Values);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_adapter_layout, parent, false);
        String tvShow = getItem(position);
        TextView theTextView = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        theTextView.setText(tvShow);
        theTextView.setBackgroundResource(false ? R.drawable.bubble1 : R.drawable.bubble2);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        theTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return theView;
    }
}
```

Comment: yuo have to use a FirebaseListAdapter instead https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html

Comment: thanks I will check now..

Comment: I treid but it says cannot reosolves firebaseadapter error, Not works

Comment: have you read the tutorial for implementing FireBase? https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: cant we do in our own listview adapter because I have already created it. you can see my coding chat adapter page.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give example of my app that working:

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(context);
Firebase ref = new Firebase("link here to your firbase");
        Firebase productsRef = ref.child("Products");//only if you have child
        FirebaseListAdapter<Product> fireAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Product>(
                getActivity(),
                Product.class, R.layout.row_main,
                productsRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View view,final Product product, final int i) {

                textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textName);
                textOverview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textOverView);
                textPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
                productImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                buttonAdd= view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
                products.add(product);
                textName.setText(product.getName().toString());
                textOverview.setText(product.getOverview().toString());
                textPrice.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice() + "₪"));
                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(product.getImageURL())
                        .into(productImage);



                buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new ProdcutFragment()).addToBackStack("tag").commit();
                        MainActivity.homeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        ProdcutFragment.sendProdcut(product);
                    }
                });




            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(fireAdapter);
```

Comment: This is using version 2.x of the Firebase SDK. While this still works, I'd recommend that developers new to Firebase use the newer version of the SDK (9.x or 10.x).

Comment: cant we do in our own listview adapter because I have already created it. you can see my coding chat adapter page.